# Conventions in assignment code?

Tags: c#

I have two classes, A and B. B knows about A, and A doesn't know about B. B has properties that can be nicely set from A, although there is no inheritance shared between A and B. There will be many times when I need to assign a B's properties from an A, but I'm looking for pointers on where I should put that code.

```
public class A
{

}

public class B
{
    //constructor?
    public B(A a)
    {
        //set b's properties from a
    }

    //factory method?
    public static B FromA(A a)
    {
        B b = new B();
        //set b's properties from a
        return b;
    }

    //setter method?
    public static void SetBFromA(B b, A a)
    {
        //set b's properties from a
    }

    //assignment method?
    public void AssignFrom(A a)
    {
        //set b's properties from a
    }
}

//static helper class?
public static class BHelper
{
    public static B GetBFromA(A a)
    {
        B b = new B();
        //set b's properties from a
        return b;
    }

    public static void SetBFromA(B b, A a)
    {
        //set b's properties from a
    }
}
```

Which, if any, of these are common practice? Do any of them carry implications based on their signature? For example, would using the constructor usually convey that the B is holding a reference to the A passed in? These are the kinds of considerations I'm thinking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the options you mention are valid. Which you would choose would depend on the particular circumstances.

```
 //constructor?
public B(A a)
{
    //set b's properties from a
}
```

The constructor pattern would be the choice when B cannot exist without the data from A.

```
//factory method?
public static B FromA(A a)
{
    B b = new B();
    //set b's properties from a
    return b;
}
```

The factory method would be the pattern of choice when the values B gets are dependant on values in A or B. Especially if B has descendants that a value in A would provide a choice of construction.

```
//setter method?
public static void SetBFromA(B b, A a)
{
    //set b's properties from a
}
```

The setter method would not be applicable in your scenario as this would be used when A and B do not know of each other and a third party needs to intercede.

```
//assignment method?
public void AssignFrom(A a)
{
    //set b's properties from a
}
```

This is essentially a visitor pattern. A visits B and leaves something of itself (thinks of bachelor days). This would be the pattern of choice if the data from A is optional for B.

Comment: Excellent response. I like the commentary on each of the suggestions I came up with, as well as the great rules-of-thumb for each. This is exactly what I was hoping to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd either use the constructor method or explicit conversion.

```
public static explicit operator B(A typ) 
{

}
```

In general, I think this is very subjective. We could all post an answer with the different method and see which one gets voted up the most, but really each way has different benefits and deficiencies. It would depend more on the context and how this pattern is done throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: Would this method go in `A` or `B`?

Comment: I don't like the idea of explicit conversion. When I see that, I assume that A and B are related in some way by inheritance, or hold exactly the same data. I much prefer the constructor method, or the factory method.

Comment: I like Yuriy's answer, especially if there is some long term or design-based linkage between A and B, but I also tend to favor the design pattern where constructors and conversion always exist in parallel. The situation in which I might use the helper class is where the linkage between A and B is incidental; e.g. A is generally useful without B and B without A, but they are used together in special situations.

Comment: @Mark H: I could see that, really depends on how related they really are. This seems very subjective without more information.

Comment: @Yuriy: StackOverflow only notifies if you include the colon.  You don't need the full name, though.  I think it'll work with four characters.  Anyhow, I'm glad you said `B`, but I'm still not entirely comfortable with it.

Comment: FYI, regardless of that prefix thing, SO also notifies the person whose answer you're commenting on, as well as the questioner.  So you should receive a notification about this.

Answer (score 3):

I'll toss out an alternative:

```
public static B CreateFromA(A a) { }
```

This uses a factory syntax, to suggest that you can crank out a `B` given an `A`, but avoiding anything that looks like a conversion.

Comment: He already suggested a factory method in the question. But +1 for having `Create` in the name.

Comment: @Mark: It was meant as an alternative to Yuriy's recommendation.  I do recognize that it's completely unoriginal.  Besides bwerks, Grant beat me to it.

Comment: Yeah, but you wrote it better than wot I did!  Still not giving you the rep though..

Comment: I think I like this as opposed to the explicit cast, since casting might imply that you're still dealing with the same object, just interpreted as a different class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a common practice as such.  When I've done this I've used the factory or constructor method.  I'd probably favour factory.

Comment: I favor factory over constructor primarily because I'm trying to avoid the look of a cast.